# Hold Gesture on Windows Store

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm writing a Windows Store version of an application that I have created for Windows Phone 8.

In my WP8 I am listening for Hold gesture event in several UIElements. For instance:

```
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas"
            Background="Transparent"
            Hold="MyCanvas_holdEvent"
            ManipulationCompleted="MyCanvas_completedEvent"
            ManipulationDelta="MyCanvas_deltaEvent" />
```

on my Windows Store version i changed Hold event to Holding event, but this event is not triggered when i'm using my mouse. I have read about GestureRecognizer and HoldingWithMouse but I don't really know how do I setup this.

Comment: Check out the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerec‌​ognizer.aspx). It explains how to create an `InputProcessor` (which accepts a `FrameworkElement` like your `Canvas`). You're on the right track by specifying `HoldingWithMouse`. In the `InputProcessor` constructor, specify [`GestureSettings.HoldingWithMouse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturesettings.aspx). [Edit: fixed link]

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!